# Calling node request from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm new to node and am practicing making http requests using the `request` module. In my script, when the user presses a button I want its callback function to make a request which gets the HTML from a webpage and filters it to get an array of data.

My server request works by itself, but when I try to combine it with HTML nothing seems to happen. My HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test1.css" />
  <script src = "posts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id = "myText">Hello, this is dog</p>
  <button onclick="getPosts()">Get Posts</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and posts.js is this:

```
var request = require('request');

function getPosts(){
    alert('Hello');
    var matches = [];
    request('https://www.reddit.com/r/TagPro/top/?sort=top&t=all', function (error, response, body) {
        // Handle errors properly.
        if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
            return res.writeHead(error ? 500 : response.statusCode);
        }

        // Accumulate the matches.
        var re = /tabindex="1" >(.+?)</g;
        var match;
        while (match = re.exec(body)) {
            matches[matches.length] = match[1];
        }
        $("#myText").text(JSON.stringify(matches));
    });
}
```

On the button press, "Hello" gets alerted but nothing happens after that it seems. Is this the proper way to link up node with front end or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running this in the browser then the problem is that you cannot use Node packages in the browser without some extra tooling.

If you check your console, you'll probably see something about "require" being `undefined`.

You should either read up on how to use tooling like Webpack (or Browserify) to make your Node packages available in the browser.

If you want to stay simple, don't use the Node requests library for client-side (browser) code. Just read up on how to make regular Ajax requests using jQuery or the native XMLHttpRequest API.

You can just replace your `request` call with something like

`$.get('http://someurl.com', function (data) { // stuff });`

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to research Browserify. I guess I still have to understand what node is actually used for, if I knew you could do this using Jquery I wouldn't have been so excited by this.

Comment: Haha. Well, feel free to accept the answer if it's what you need. Node is mainly for server side code but with some tricks you can do more :)